# Index Match with multiple references

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDULs.jpg)

```
Item ID Description Fifteen Digit   Fourteen Digit  Thirteen Digit  Twelve Digit    Eleven Digit    Ten Digit   Nine Digit  Eight Digit Seven Digit Six Digit       Item ID
1100001 POS - BANK MACHINE  -   -   -   -   -   1100001123  110000112   11000011    1100001 -   ABC 1100001
1100280 ALIEN EDP 30 ML (30x1)  -   -   -   -   -   1100280123  110028012   11002801    1100280 -   ABC 1100280
1100288 IN LOVE WITH DIOR COFFRET   -   11002881100288  -   -   -   -   -   -   1100288 -   ABC 1100288
1100297 LACOSTE INSPIRATION 75ML    -   11002971100297  -   -   -   -   -   -   1100297 -   ABC 1100297



                Barcode Item ID Description                         
                1100280123
```

Hi I want to look up the Item ID, there are multiple barcodes for one item ID. If I put any barcode than its should provide its respective Item ID.

Please help me out on this. I tried index match with LEN (to count no. of digits in a barcode), but it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enter the following following formula in `Cell F10`

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$5,MIN(IF($E10=$C$2:$L$5,ROW($C$2:$L$5)-1)))
```

This is an array formula so commit it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. Drag/Copy to `Cell G10` and if required drag/copy down. See image for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that A1:N5 contains the data, and that H10 contains the bar code of interest, enter the following formula in I10, confirm with `CONTROL+SHIFT+ENTER`, and copy to J10...

```
=INDEX(A$1:A$5,SMALL(IF($C$1:$L$5=$H10,ROW($C$1:$L$5)-ROW($C$1)+1),1))
```

Note that the formula can be copied down the columns, if necessary.

Hope this helps!